# Make query to be not equal

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have Codeigniter application i have condition that find user (id) from [user] table if equal to (user) from [courses] table i want to reverse "=>" to be not equal

this code:

```
                            foreach ($courses as $c){
                            $where= array('id'=>$c->student);
```

Comment: can you explain your question better?!

Comment: Nothing about this question looks like a CodeIgniter query to me.  Have you researched at all?

Answer (score -1):

Cant you ad another foreach statment

```
foreach ($courses as $c){
foreach ($c as $key => $value){

if($value != 'student'){$dosomething;}

}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I don't understand what is your expectation, but here.

if you want to query with db query builder from codeigniter, and try to define "NOT EQUAL" just add  `!=`.

So, try to replace this
`$where= array('id'=>$c->student);`

To this:

`$where= array('id !=' => $c->student);`

Or this is my recommendation:

`$where= ('id !=', $c->student);`

after that, you can use builder like:

```
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->from('user u');
        $this->db->join('courses c', 'c.user_id = u.id');
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

Then full code:

```
foreach ($courses as $c){
$where= ('id !=', $c->student);
 $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->from('user u');
        $this->db->join('courses c', 'c.user_id = u.id');
        $this->db->where($where); 
// or you can try direct subtitute $this->db->where('id !=', $c->student);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();

      foreach($result => $res){
echo $res->name; # OR YOUR EXPECTED COLUMN
}

}
```

Comment: This question was Too Broad / under-researched.   That said, the isolated question was a duplicate and therefore was better closed than answered so that Stack Overflow doesn't have to store redundant content.

Comment: Making iterated queries is not good advice.  I would be chaining these query builder methods.  The `select()` is not necessary. https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#:~:text=If you are selecting all,*’.  Your `$where` syntax is flawed.